# Syntax error in Makefile: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")

Tags: bash, makefile, syntax-error

Here is my make target:

```
copy_python:
    if test -d $(VIRTUAL_ENV)/lib; then \
        cp -a $(VIRTUAL_ENV)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. ./package/tmp/; \
    fi
    if test -d $(VIRTUAL_ENV)/lib64; then \
        cp -a $(VIRTUAL_ENV)/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/. ./package/tmp/; \ 
    fi
```

Here is the error:

```
/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'copy_python' failed
make: *** [copy_python] Error 2
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: Can we see the first few lines of the Makefile?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Answer (score 11):

You have an extra space after the ending backslash, at the end of the second `cp` command. For this reason, `\` no longer acts as a line continuation and the `fi` on the next line is not passed to `sh`

Comment: Yep, it's a space at the end of the line with the second `cp` command. I can tell because it's actually preserved in the pasted code snippet! This is why it's best to copy & paste code in questions, rather than retyping.

Comment: Thank you @GordonDavisson, I have rephrased my answer accordingly.